# Power supply with output of 24V, 500mA

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer, power-electronics, autotransformer

I am currently trying to design a power supply (non-isolated) with input of 440V AC and output of 24V/500mA. Can I use an autotransformer for this? I know I can use conventional transformer, but I want to know whether autotransformer will be a feasible option or not.

Comment: Probably yes, but at 12 VA, I doubt you will save anything compared to a real full isolation transformer.

Comment: This seems as though you have got an idea into your head and may be trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. We can't answer this because we don't know what you are powering and what problems might arise.

Comment: If it is feasible or not depends on what other options you have available that may or may not be feasible options.

Comment: Say you already had a transformer in the system with a multi-tap primary and a 120V secondary (actual voltage not critical). If the input taps were 415 and 440, then you’d have 25VAC  between those taps by virtue of the autotransformer action. Without such shenanigans, i’d suggest finding a ‘normal’ transformer would be easier.

Comment: regarding the  application i am basically designing it for protecting my contractors from fluctuations in  supply voltage ,i would require regulated  24 Volt supply be it ac or dc .

Answer (score 0):

You might mean you already have an autotransformer connected across the primary line, and it has a 24 volt tap. Then one diode and one capacitor could be connected to provide ample DC voltage. A voltage regulator and another capacitor might be added if stable voltage is required.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently trying to design a power supply (non-isolated) with input of 440V AC and output of 24V/500mA. Can I use an autotransformer for this? I know I can use conventional transformer, but I want to know whether autotransformer will be a feasible option or not.

> regarding the application i am basically designing it for protecting my contractors from fluctuations in supply voltage ,i would require regulated 24 Volt supply be it ac or dc .

It is presumed that you are designing electrical controls, e.g. motor control, working off 3 x 415 V ~ 50 Hz (3 x 440 V only in Columbia).

Considering safety aspects, isolation is a must for the control circuit, irrespective of the control voltage being 220V ~ or 24 V =.

Hence an unisolated, autotransformer-based 24V = supply is a definite no-no.

Regulated power supplies would be unnecessary, taking into account the acceptable voltage tolerance with regard to switchgear.

For 24 V = controls, a 3 phase unregulated power supply would suffice.